# Hide second table in ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I'm using two tables within a Repeater to display the customer Logo and Comments and in the second table, another Logo and the Reply to the comment. 
But I don't always have a Reply to display. How can I hide the second table when there is no reply to display. I've done it successfully using Dynamic c# and placeholder, but I would like to achieve the same result in ASP.NET, unless Dynamic C# is more efficient.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="border: Black; align-content: center">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden">
                    <div>
                        <telerik:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="image1" DataValue='<%#Eval("logo1") %>'
                            AutoAdjustImageControlSize="false" Width="100px" Height="75px"
                            DefaultImageUrl="~/Images/BlankPerson.png" Style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden">
                    <div>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="label3" runat="server" border="0" Width="30px" Height="75px"
                            Style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden">
                    <div>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="label4" runat="server" border="0" Width="600px" Height="75px"
                            Text='<%#Eval("Comment")%>' TextMode="MultiLine"
                            Style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="atable2" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="border: Black; align-content: center">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden">
                    <div>
                        <telerik:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="RadBinaryImage1" DataValue='<%#Eval("logo2") == DBNull.Value ? null : Eval("logo2") %>'
                            AutoAdjustImageControlSize="false" Width="100px" Height="75px"
                            DefaultImageUrl="~/Images/BlankPerson.png" Style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden">
                    <div>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" border="0" Width="30px" Height="75px"
                            Style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden">
                    <div>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" border="0" Width="600px" Height="75px"
                            Text='<%#Eval("Reply") == DBNull.Value ? "" : Eval("Reply") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"
                            resize="none" overflow="hidden" Style="border: none; resize: none; overflow: hidden" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition of second table tag by adding `runat="server"` attribute:

```
<table id="atable2" 
       border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" 
       style="border: Black; align-content: center" 
       runat="server">
```

Then attach `OnItemDataBound` event handler to repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" 
              runat="server" 
              OnItemDataBound="RepeaterItemDataBound">
```

And here is the code for `OnItemDataBound` event handler:

```
protected void RepeaterItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // change the code here to get if you need show a second table
        bool reply = (bool)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Reply"); 

        if (reply)
        {
            HtmlTable atable2 = e.Item.FindControl("atable2") as HtmlTable;

            if (atable2 != null)
            {
                atable2.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```